# CADENCE wireless connection

Tags: wireless, software, vlsi, cadence

I would like to know if you have a way to call without needing a line of communication at CADENCE?

See the example in the PROTEUS software image, at the time I made the connections without needing the lines, this makes the visualization less polluted and easier to locate the components in the schematic.

I will be grateful if someone provides a link or PDF of a complete CADENCE tutorial.

[image]

Comment: It's called a net alias or net name.

Answer (score 1):

With most CAD systems you can attach a "net name" to a wire, and all wires with the same net name will be connected together, without actually drawing a wire between them.

Note that placing a net name should be a specific function of the program - just placing random text beside a wire will not name it.

Comment: I don't know if this was a communication failure because of the language transfer, but I mean: I want to make a wireless call using a PIN. I don't know which command or icon is connected from one end to the other without using wires. I took an example from Proteus because I know it is possible to do this.

Repeat I don't want to use wires I want to use this connection model.

I just can't find it in CADENCE.

NOTE: it has the PIN, but in this case I realized that used to make the call in the layout, it does not occur in the schematic.

Comment: In the CAD systems I've used, you can't put a net name directly on a component pin - you need to draw a short bit of wire, and put the net name on that.  Possible language/translation problem: when you say "wireless call using PIN" I think of using a cell phone or radio to pass information, not indicating connections on a schematic.